# Extracting source code from R functions in RStoolbox

Tags: r

I am trying to access the underlying code to the `tasseledCap` function in `RSToolbox` in R, but have been unable to view some of the, I think, internal functions.

Specifically, in the `tasseledCap` function, I am wanting to see what `.TCcoefs` and `.paraRasterFun` do.

I have looked at the source code on github, but can't quite find it. Does anyone know how to access this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These objects are created by a script when RStoolbox library is loaded.

Check the script here: [Generate SysData](https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/blob/master/data-raw/generate_sysdata.R)

Comment: BTW, .paraRasterFun is in the internalFunctions.R script